# iOS: Displaying a new modal view on top of master (root) view in split view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, view, split

I need to call a new modal view in the master view area after selecting a specific object from the initial list (tableview).

Tried this:

```
//new view init:
    clientList *clientListCon = [[clientList alloc] initWithNibName:@"clientList" bundle:nil];
//pushing   
 [[splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] presentModalViewController:clientListCon animated:YES];
```

All I get:

```
MultipleDetailViews[12997:40b] -[UITableView presentModalViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x584d800
2011-03-18 14:40:51.449 MultipleDetailViews[12997:40b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableView presentModalViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x584d800'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017035a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01857313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017050bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01674966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01674522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   MultipleDetailViews                 0x00008051 -[RootViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 354
    6   UIKit                               0x00a8fb68 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1140
    7   UIKit                               0x00a85b05 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 219
    8   Foundation                          0x0079779e __NSFireDelayedPerform + 441
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x016e48c3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x016e5e74 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1220
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x016422c9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x01641840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x01641761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x0205a1c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x0205a289 GSEventRun + 115
    16  UIKit                               0x00a26c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    17  MultipleDetailViews                 0x000069a4 main + 102
    18  MultipleDetailViews                 0x00006935 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it ought to be:

```
[self presentModalViewController:clientListCon animated:YES];
```

I have no idea how you are getting a reference to a UITableView from the provided code though.

Comment: In this case, the clientListCon is opened in full screen mode. I want it to cover the root view only.

Comment: UITable comes from the general SplitView declaration
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 //I need:
 NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
if (row == 0) {
push a new modal controller}
    }

Comment: it is doable with:
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:clientListCon animated:YES];
but I am looking for a way to display a modal view without using the navigation controller.

Comment: The effect that you are looking for is fairly specialized, and you aren't going to find any out of the box solutions.